# UWP WebRequest Replacement HttpClient Cookie?

Tags: cookies, win-universal-app

As i am either too dump to find the proper answer or it is simply not out there ... how the hek i replace the "outdated" WebRequest properly with the HttpClient "replacement"?

In the WebRequest i tendet to serialize & analyze the actual cookie as the webpage returns a partial JSON cookie ... however ... i still did not found a way to get a proper CookieContainer (or whatever form of cookie) from the frking HttpClient ... also ... every google request leads me to 20000000 years old answers or outdated documents (+ some upToDate docs which all just refer to "GET" requests without any cookies involved -.-*))

would be kindfull if somebody could lead me to the correct path ...
thx

greets
X39

```
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(app.Settings.UserAgent);
var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(app.Settings.Pr0grammUrl.Api + "user/login"), new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent(postDataBuilder.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) handles cookies by itself through the default [HttpBaseProtocolFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.aspx). You can get cookies associated with a URI through [GetCookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.web.http.httpcookiemanager.getcookies.aspx) method of the [HttpCookieManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.web.http.httpcookiemanager.aspx) class:

> Gets an HttpCookieCollection that contains the HttpCookie instances
>   that are associated with a specific URI.

```
using (var protocolFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter()) {
    var cookieManager = protocolFilter.CookieManager;
    var cookies = cookieManager.GetCookies(uri);
    foreach (var cookie in cookies) {
       // Here is each cookie
    }
}
```

You should also be able to set/get cookies through HTTP request and response headers. To disallow HttpClient from handling cookies by itself, create an instance of HttpBaseProtocolFilter and set the [CookieUsageBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.cookieusagebehavior.aspx) to HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies:

> NoCookies: Do not handle cookies automatically.

```
// Create http filter
httpFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
httpFilter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;

// Create http client
httpClient = new HttpClient(httpFilter);

// Handle cookies through HTTP headers
```